# Block A Number From Leaving Voicemail?

Tags: call-screening, voicemail

I keep getting spam calls from a number every night at midnight. I've blocked it, but now it just goes to voicemail and I have to delete the voice messages every morning. It's annoying. Is there an option to block it from leaving voice messages, or just automatically answer then hang up? I haven't found one in Android itself (my phone has ICS). <strike>I've also tried [Mr. Number](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mrnumber.blocker), which I thought would do this, but it doesn't.</strike> **It does work, see update below**. I've also talked to my carrier about it, but apparently I'd have to add "smart number blocking" or something to my plan for about $5 a month. If possible, I'd rather just get an app answer & hang up than have another fee to pay.

**Delayed Update**: I followed the directions eldarerathis provided below for Mr. Number and it does what I was trying to do; I must have just done something wrong before. The phone will still ring for a few seconds though, so it may be best to silence it if the call comes at a consistent, inconvenient time like it does for me.

Comment: How did you set up Mr. Number? It maintains two block lists, and one should be to answer + hang up immediately (the other is straight to voicemail). I use it exactly like you're describing. What happened when you tried to use it?

Comment: It claimed it was blocking the number, but I was still getting voicemails. How did you make it answer & hang up?

Comment: I opened the app, pressed the blocklist button in the top right (the circle with a line through it) and then it gave me three tabs: "Hang up", "Voicemail" and "Exceptions". Then I pressed the "Hang up on Someone" button on the first tab to add the number I wanted to block. This is on a Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: This can also be done with Tasker.

Comment: I'll try Mr. Number again--I don't think those were _quite_ the same steps I took before, so I'll give it another go. I would try Tasker too, but $7 seems like a lot...

Comment: To keep this phone number from ringing, create a contact for it and then follow one of these options: http://articles.businessinsider.com/2011-07-10/tech/29961867_1_ringtone-free-app-android-market.

Comment: Why not go to your carrier and ask them to blacklist the number so that it would *never* reach your voicemail?

Comment: @t0mm13b I asked them about that once. "Smart Number Blocking" is $5 a month, Mr. Number is free.

Comment: Mr Number is spyware garbage. It's not just an app, but a service; to use it you have to create a Mr. Number account on their site, whereby you agree to their terms of service. Your phone will upload info to the site, like your list of contacts. It is ironic for an app to increase your privacy (block unwanted calls) to compromise your privacy in this way, and from a technical standpoint, the level of complexity is unacceptable, since the problem can be solved locally on the phone without contacting a service.

Comment: I have tried numerous applications which claim they can do this, none of which worked. Call Blocker from embware finally seems to be doing it. It has a global setting for the behavior which applies to your entire black list (not per entry). Set it to "answer then hangup" and it does the job. You may have to remove the target number from the phone's built in blocker. Only two numbers leave voice mails, so I will transition them to this app and leave the rest to be handled by the phone's regular app.

Comment: @Kaz I don't remember having to make an account, and I can't find anything account-related in the settings. What makes you think it's spyware?

Comment: @Zelda64fan  It is spelled out in the Mr. Number terms of service: "You may join Mr. Number and become a “Member” by installing the Mr. Number Mobile App on your mobile phone. The first time you launch the Mr. Number Mobile App, a Caller ID record will be created for you automatically and linked to your phone number. When you use the Mr. Number Mobile App, you will have the opportunity to decide what Caller ID Data that other Members will see when you call or text them."

Comment: @Zelda64fan About a year ago they [got in hot water](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/09/04/popular-caller-id-app-mr-number-forced-to-disable-crowd-sourced-caller-id-feature-due-to-a-change-in-googles-tos/) with Google. Interestingly, since May of this year, though, Mr. Number has been owned by White Pages, evidently.

Answer (score 1):

Not for Ice Cream Sandwich, but in Marshmallow, the stock call blocking also deletes voicemail.

Phone->Menu->Settings->"Call Blocking"

> Calls from these numbers will be blocked and voicemails will be automatically deleted.

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist in Nougat on version 11 of the Phone app from Google.

Answer (score 0):

The free App call control works pretty good. You can have a number blocked and set up so it picks it up and hangs up. It doesn't let them leave a message and your phone don't ring. However If you go where you don't have service it will still send it to voicemail, but works great otherwise.