# blocking callers from leaving voicemail

Tags: call-screening, voicemail

how do I block a caller from leaving a voice mail on a prepaid plan.I have a lg g2?  I don't want a certin person to leave a volcemail

Comment: Voicemail is handled by your carrier, you should talk to them.  Best you could do is have your phone answer and automatically hang up (which does nothing if it's off or the call doesn't go through), but I don't know of an app that does that since Android does its best to prevent it.

Comment: @MatthewRead there are several [Call Blocker](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_97) apps doing just that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Block A Number From Leaving Voicemail?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40110/block-a-number-from-leaving-voicemail)

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to take a look at [Extreme Call Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greythinker.punchback). That app is on Playstore for already 5 years, and claims to work from Gingerbread (2.3.3) up to Lollipop. One of the explicitely listed features is:

> New blocking feature: Allow the call to ring through, but prevent it from leaving voice mail.

Which should be exactly what you're after. For possible alternatives, be welcome to take a look at my list of [Call Blocker](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_97) apps.